# Going to next object in collection on a keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing some code to prevent sending form with empty inputs. My code searches all inputs with attribute is_required and changes their class with creating a popover from Bootstrap.
What I wanna do is to write something what will give a popover only to first empty input,
remove class `input-error` with destroying a popover when I will do a keypress on this, and adding a popover to next element in collection, until last object. 
But I don't know how to do this. I'm new in javascript, but I notice that creating a function in a for loop is not a good idea. Any ideas how to make this work?
My code:

```
$('input[id=check]').click(function() {
    var x = $("input[is_required]").filter(function() {
        return $(this).val().trim() == ''; 
    });

   var y = $("select[is_required]").filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() == 0;
    }); 

    var z = x.add(y);
    if ($(z).data() == null) {
        $("form").submit();
    };

    $(x).each(function () {
        $(this).val('');
        $(this).addClass("input-error");
        $(this).attr({
            "data-toggle": "popover",
            "data-container": "body",
            "data-content": "Wypełnij to pole",
            "data-trigger": "manual"
        });
        $(this).popover('show');
        $(this).keypress(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("input-error");
            $(this).popover('destroy');
            i++;
        });
    });

   if($(x).length > 0) {
      $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $(x[0]).offset().top-100
      }, 200);
   }
});
```

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/change/ You can use it to do something if the value in the input box changes... e.g. if it changes and the element `$(elem).hasClass('input-error')`, then `$(elem).removeClass('input-error')`

Comment: Also, don't use variables called `x`, `y` and `z`... unless they're 3D coordinates or something. Call them "invalidInputs" or something meaningful, otherwise others won't get what they are easily.

Comment: I know, but I have .keypress() function here. It doesn't matter how I will catching when value in input will change. Problem is how to switch popover to next empty input until collection will end.

Comment: I don't know what "switch popover to next empty input" means. Are you trying to find the next sibling(s) in the DOM that is an input? If so, you might want http://api.jquery.com/next/ (e.g. `$(thisInput).next('input')`)

Comment: Sorry, I trying to write in english but it's not my native language.
So, let's say that I left some inputs empty. I want to write code who will add input-error class to all empty input, and a popover to first empty input. When I will start writing something in input with popover, popover and class will be deleted from this input, and popover will be displayed on next empty input.